# Redux : Cannot pass nested variable to action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to pass `suggestion._id` to my action as `response_id` on `onClick`  but some reason I'm receiving `[object%20Object]` in console. I tried `response_id: suggestion._id` in order to declare it first but didn't work.

Action :

```
export const deleteResponse = (id, response_id) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`/api/suggestions/response/${id}/${response_id}`);
    dispatch({ type: DELETE_REPONSE, payload: response_id });
    dispatch(setAlert('Review removed', 'success'));
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: RESPONSE_ERROR,
      payload: {
        msg: err.response,
        status: err.response.status,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

Component in frontend:

```
 <Box mt='auto'>
      <Flex justifyContent={'space-between'} mb='2'>
        {suggestion._id}
        <Box my='auto'>
          {!auth.loading && user === auth.user._id && (
            <Button
              type='button'
              
              onClick={(e) =>
                deleteResponse(id, {
                  response_id: suggestion._id,
                })
              }
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
          )}
        </Box>
      </Flex>
     
    </Box>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you forgot to destructure, you need to do it like this:

```
export const deleteResponse = (id, { response_id }) => async dispatch => {
```

Comment: Thank you so much I really struggled with this. Please if you don't mind, I'm learning Javascript and MERN right now, do you have any resources I can check in order to learn more about it?

Comment: You're welcome. here in StackOverflow you can learn a lot, also Udemy can be a good place to learn. and if you don't mind please accept my answer (the V icon) :)

Comment: Do you have anything particular ? Like a personal recommendation ? Also I can't accept yet I need to wait 5 minutes.

Comment: I don't have anything particular, I would recommend you to peak a good React course with a lot of students

Comment: will do. Thanks again.